# Vnet creation task skip the task if it is run once

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am working to build a ci/cd pipeline for AKS. the first task set is "Azure resource group deployment" which is used for creating vnet /subnet for the AKS .
The intention is to skip the task next time onwards since the vnet and subnet are already in place. Second time onwards getting the following error -

```
BadRequest: { "error": { "code": "InUseSubnetCannotBeDeleted", "message": "Subnet AKSSubnet is in use by /subscriptions/***************************************/resourceGroups/MC_**************-CLUSTER_eastus/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/aks-agentpool-
########-nic-0/ipConfigurations/ipconfig1 and cannot be deleted. In order to delete the subnet, delete all the resources within the subnet. See aka.ms/deletesubnet.", "details": [] } }  
Error:  Task failed while creating or updating the template deployment.
```

Looks like the task is trying to delete the subnet instead of skipping it. What is the resolution?

It is using following arm templates : azuredeploy.json

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "vnetName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "GEN-VNET-NAME",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of the virtual Network"
      }
    },
    "vnetAddressPrefix": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "10.10.0.0/16",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Address prefix"
      }
    },
    "subnetPrefix": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "10.10.0.0/24",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Subnet Prefix"
      }
    },
    "subnetName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Subnet",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "GEN-SUBNET-NAME"
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {},
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
      "name": "[parameters('vnetName')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "properties": {
        "addressSpace": {
          "addressPrefixes": [
            "[parameters('vnetAddressPrefix')]"
          ]
        }
      },
      "resources": [
        {
          "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
          "type": "subnets",
          "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
          "name": "[parameters('subnetName')]",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[parameters('vnetName')]"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "addressPrefix": "[parameters('subnetPrefix')]"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {
    "vnetName": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[parameters('vnetName')]"
    },
    "subnetName": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[parameters('subnetName')]"
    }
  }
}
```

azuredeploy.parameters.json

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "vnetName": {
      "value": "###########"
    },
    "vnetAddressPrefix": {
      "value": "10.10.0.0/16"
    },
    "subnetPrefix": {
      "value": "10.10.0.0/24"
    },
    "subnetName": {
      "value": "######"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you clarify what are the condition you run the task with? i.e. always running it? Or do you have a condition on it? Which 'action' of the task are you using? Please note that the you could be using 'incremental mode' of Azure Templates, and they will ensure to skip what does not need to be run again (e.g. if an resource is created and it is in your _desired state_, then it will not be affected by the task execution).

Comment: this is misleading, deployment mode doesn't matter, it doesn't really skip resources, it just does not update them if there is nothing to update, essentially it calls the api, but as there are no changes to be made - nothing is happening

Comment: @ luca cappa   have used the incremental mode .As the error shows, it still try to delete the exisitng subnet and then probably will try to build the subnet .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening right here - your template is coded in such a fashion:

```
vnet resources
  empty subnets property
subnet resource(s)
bla-bla-bla
```

and what is happening here it is trying to coerce the vnet to have 0 subnets, due to how you authored your template. you have 2 options:

1. put a condition on the vnet resource definition and pass a parameter to it if the build number is greater than 1 (or just manually specify at build time whether to skip it or not).
2. modify your template to look like so:

```
vnet resource
  subnets property populated with subnets
bla-bla-bla
```

essentially, this has nothing to do with Azure Devops.

Comment: have updated json used for the vnet /subnet creation . Not sure where it is going wrong ..

Comment: you didnt really change anything, since you still use resources under vnets, not a subnet property. take a look at a [proper way](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/201-vnet-2subnets-service-endpoints-storage-integration/azuredeploy.json#L129) of doing this

Comment: I checked the link however it is not clear about how the variable for build number will be set to skip future build runs. any insight /help is much appreciated

Comment: it wont, it just wont break them (your subnets). you can figure out a way to implement the skip if you can make sure your first build id is always the same (by passing it to the arm template and using a condition on the vnet resource)