# Subnet DemoSubnet is in use and cannot be updated

Tags: azure

I have created a DemoSubnet and an ElasticIP, then I am trying to deploy a ARM template which has a Virtual machine which is trying to attach with that existing elastic IP. The template works fine initially, and after some time its failing due to below error

> "At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list
>   deployment operations for details"

Here is the detailed error message from the arm template deployment:

> Details=[{"code":"BadRequest","message":"{\r\n  \"error\": {\r\n
>   \"code\": \"InUseSubnetCannotBeUpdated\",\r\n    \"message\": \"Subnet
>   DemoSubnet is in use and cannot be updated.\",\r\n    \"details\":
>   []\r\n  }\r\n}"}]

ARM Temaplate

{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "addressPrefixes": {
            "defaultValue": [
                "10.0.0.0/16"
            ],
           "type": "Array",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Address prefix of the virtual network"
            }
        },
        "location": {
            "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Location for all resources."
            }
        },
        "publicIpNewOrExisting": {
            "defaultValue": "existing",
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Determines whether or not a new public ip should be provisioned."
            }
        },
        "publicIpResourceGroupName": {
            "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().name]",
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Name of the resource group for the public ip address"
            }
        },
        "storageAccountResourceGroupName": {
            "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().name]",
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Name of the resource group for the existing storage account"
            }
        },
        "storageNewOrExisting": {
            "defaultValue": "existing",
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Determines whether or not a new storage account should be provisioned."
            }
        },
        "subnetPrefix": {
            "defaultValue": "10.0.0.0/24",
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Subnet prefix of the virtual network"
            }
        },
        "virtualNetworkNewOrExisting": {
            "defaultValue": "existing",
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Determines whether or not a new virtual network should be provisioned."
            }
        },
        "virtualNetworkResourceGroupName": {
            "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().name]",
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Name of the resource group for the existing virtual network"
            }
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
            "apiVersion": "2018-10-01",
            "name": "SampleVM",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId(parameters('storageAccountResourceGroupName'),'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', 'SampleStorageAccnt')]",
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/', 'SampleNIF')]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "diagnosticsProfile": {
                    "bootDiagnostics": {
                        "enabled": true,
                        "storageUri": "[reference(resourceId(parameters('storageAccountResourceGroupName'),'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', 'SampleStorageAccnt')).primaryEndpoints.blob]"
                    }
                },
                "hardwareProfile": {
                    "vmSize": "Standard_A2"
                },
                "networkProfile": {
                    "networkInterfaces": [
                        {
                            "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces','SampleNIF')]"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "osProfile": {
                    "adminPassword": "rajnikaur@253",
                    "adminUsername": "adminuser",
                    "computerName": "SampleVM"
                },
                "storageProfile": {
                    "dataDisks": [
                        {
                            "createOption": "Empty",
                            "diskSizeGB": 1023,
                            "lun": 0
                        }
                    ],
                    "imageReference": {
                        "offer": "WindowsServer",
                        "publisher": "MicrosoftWindowsServer",
                        "sku": "2016-Datacenter",
                        "version": "latest"
                    },
                    "osDisk": {
                        "createOption": "FromImage"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
            "apiVersion": "2019-04-01",
            "name": "SampleStorageAccnt",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "kind": "Storage",
            "condition": "[equals(parameters('storageNewOrExisting'), 'existing')]"
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
            "apiVersion": "2019-09-01",
            "name": "SampleNIF",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId(parameters('virtualNetworkResourceGroupName'),'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', 'sampleVnet')]",
                "[resourceId(parameters('publicIpResourceGroupName'),'Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses', 'DemoEIP')]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "ipConfigurations": [
                    {
                        "name": "ipconfig",
                        "properties": {
                            "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
                            "publicIPAddress": {
                                "id": "[resourceId(parameters('publicIpResourceGroupName'),'Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses', 'DemoEIP')]"
                            },
                            "subnet": {
                                "id": "[resourceId(parameters('virtualNetworkResourceGroupName'),'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', 'sampleVnet', 'DemoSubnet')]"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses",
            "apiVersion": "2017-09-01",
            "name": "DemoEIP",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "properties": {
                "publicIPAllocationMethod": "Static"
            },
            "condition": "[equals(parameters('publicIpNewOrExisting'), 'existing')]"
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
            "apiVersion": "2017-09-01",
            "name": "sampleVnet",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "properties": {
                "addressSpace": {
                    "addressPrefixes": "[parameters('addressPrefixes')]"
                },
                "subnets": [
                    {
                        "name": "DemoSubnet",
                        "properties": {
                            "addressPrefix": "[parameters('subnetPrefix')]"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "condition": "[equals(parameters('virtualNetworkNewOrExisting'), 'existing')]"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: Could you show your full template?

Comment: I'd suggest you share the template, but I suspect something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59484247/vnet-creation-task-skip-the-task-if-it-is-run-once/59484954) is happening.

Comment: "subnets": [{
                        "name": "DemoSubnet",
                        "properties": {
                            "addressPrefix": "[parameters('subnetPrefix')]"
                        }
                    }
                ] and in Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces ipconfigurations adding subnets as "subnet": {
                                "id": "[resourceId(parameters('virtualNetworkResourceGroupName'),'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', 'sampleVnet', 'DemoSubnet')]"
                            }

Comment: just post the whole template into the question

Comment: added whole arm template

Comment: I have fix the problem. Thanks All :)